# NEST API Default value for GeoShapes fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are using a filter as per following:

```
filters.Add(fq => fq
    .Term(t => t
        .Field(f => f.LocalityId)
        .Value(locationParams[2])) || fq
    .GeoShape(g => g
        .Field("locationShape")
        .Relation(GeoShapeRelation.Within)
        .IndexedShape(f => f
            .Id(searchCriteria.spLocationId)
            .Index(indexName)
            .Path("geometry")
        )
    )
);
```

However, if the **geometry** field is missing, Elasticsearch throws an exception.

Is there anyway to avoid this by using a default (Null Value) in the mapping or any other way.

Comment: does `ignore_unmapped` help here? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html#_ignore_unmapped_4

Comment: @RussCam No it does not. This property works in the first Field value in the Term query where we do not need it as the location values exist - but this option does not even exist (intellisense) in the second part where the geometry is defined. It is the missing Geometry field that throws the exceptions.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: @RussCam 7.7 for both.

Comment: @RussCam Do you any other ideas of how we can solve this problem as it is causing our system major issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to avoid the exception in this case. Elasticsearch assumes that the parameters that the user provides to a pre-indexed shape are valid.

Ideally, the values supplied to the indexed shape should be constrained in a manner that prevents an end user from supplying invalid values. If that is unfeasible, you could run a `bool` query with filter clauses of `exists` query and `ids` query on the `indexName` index before adding the indexed shape geoshape  query filter to the search request.

For example

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var documentsIndex = "documents";
    var shapesIndex = "shapes";
    var host = "localhost";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri($"http://{host}:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultMappingFor<Document>(m => m.IndexName(documentsIndex))
        .DefaultMappingFor<Shape>(m => m.IndexName(shapesIndex));

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.Indices.Exists(documentsIndex).Exists)
        client.Indices.Delete(documentsIndex);

    client.Indices.Create(documentsIndex, c => c
        .Map<Document>(m => m
            .AutoMap()
        )
    );

    if (client.Indices.Exists(shapesIndex).Exists)
        client.Indices.Delete(shapesIndex);

    client.Indices.Create(shapesIndex, c => c
        .Map<Shape>(m => m
            .AutoMap()
        )
    );

    client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany(new [] { 
            new Document 
            {
                Id = 1,
                LocalityId = 1,
                LocationShape = GeoWKTReader.Read("POLYGON ((30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20))")
            },
            new Document
            {
                Id = 2,
                LocalityId = 2
            },
        })
        .IndexMany(new [] 
        {
            new Shape 
            {
                Id = 1,
                Geometry = GeoWKTReader.Read("POLYGON ((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35))")
            }
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    var shapeId = 1;

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Shape>(s => s
        .Size(0)
        .Query(q => +q
            .Ids(i => i.Values(shapeId)) && +q
            .Exists(e => e.Field("geometry"))
        )
    );

    Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Document>, QueryContainer> geoShapeQuery = q => q;

    if (searchResponse.Total == 1)
        geoShapeQuery = q => +q
            .GeoShape(g => g
                .Field("locationShape")
                .Relation(GeoShapeRelation.Within)
                .IndexedShape(f => f
                    .Id(shapeId)
                    .Index(shapesIndex)
                    .Path("geometry")
                )
            );

    client.Search<Document>(s => s
        .Query(q => +q
            .Term(t => t
                .Field(f => f.LocalityId)
                .Value(2)
            ) || geoShapeQuery(q)
        )
    );
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LocalityId { get; set; }
    public IGeoShape LocationShape { get; set; }
}

public class Shape
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IGeoShape Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

If `var shapeId = 1;` is changed to `var shapeId = 2;` then the geoshape query is not added to the filter clauses when searching on the documents index.