# NEST and Elasticsearch 7.7 Empty Geometries

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Based on the OGC Simple Features standard, can one use a default of POLYGON(EMPTY) for GeoShape field types for missing values in Elasticsearch.

If not, how can one provide an empty Geometry for the field if it has no value.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: [NEST API Default value for GeoShapes fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913118/nest-api-default-value-for-geoshapes-fields)

Comment: @RussCam It is to do with the same problem but we though trying the Polygon (EMPTY) might be a solution as no one seems to be able to address this problem!

Answer (score 0):

`POLYGON (EMPTY)` is not supported.

You can instead sync null-values and then query against them using an inverted `exists` query:

```
PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST example/_doc
{
  "location": "POLYGON ((100.0 0.0, 101.0 0.0, 101.0 1.0, 100.0 1.0, 100.0 0.0))"
}

POST example/_doc
{
  "location": null
}
```

```
GET example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "location"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### --- OR ---

You can take advantage of `ignore_malformed` and sync your `POLYGON (EMPTY)` nonetheless:

```
PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_shape",
        "ignore_malformed": true     <----
      }
    }
  }
}

POST example/_doc
{
  "location": "POLYGON ((100.0 0.0, 101.0 0.0, 101.0 1.0, 100.0 1.0, 100.0 0.0))"
}

POST example/_doc
{
  "location": "POLYGON (EMPTY)"
}
```

You'll still be able to do this:

```
GET example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "location"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but the response will be somewhat more distinctive:

```
{
  "_index":"example",
  "_type":"_doc",
  "_id":"Z-iPV3IBG_KW3EFnzAYA",
  "_score":0.0,
  "_ignored":[
    "location"
  ],
  "_source":{
    "location":"POLYGON (EMPTY)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. We need to use it in a filter like : filters.Add(fq => fq
    .Term(t => t
        .Field(f => f.LocalityId)
        .Value(locationParams[2])) || fq
    .GeoShape(g => g
        .Field("locationShape")
        .Relation(GeoShapeRelation.Within)
        .IndexedShape(f => f
            .Id(searchCriteria.spLocationId)
            .Index(indexName)
            .Path("geometry")
        )
    )
);

Comment: That will throw an exception if Path("geometry") is missing.

Comment: Try the above mapping. Missing geometries should be skipped.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not in the above scenario! That is why we are having so much problem.